# React onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave didn't work as expected (strange behaviour)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create indicator for my grid item so it will give red mark as background color. but it seems react very slow on modify the DOM, and make some component not updated

here is my code,
i loop the item

```
{(function(rows, i, len) {
    while (++i <= len) {
    rows.push (<div
        key={i.toString()}
        className={"col-sm-3 bg-light mb-1 p-3 parent"}
        style={that.styles.item}
        onMouseEnter={that.itemMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={that.itemMouseLeave}>
        <center>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style={that.styles.closeButton}>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div className="rounded-circle img-responsive mb-3" style={that.styles.image} />
            <h4>VicoErv</h4>
        </center>
    </div>)
    }

    return rows;
})([], 0, 10)}
```

And the item listener

```
itemMouseEnter(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let elem = event.target;

    elem.classList.remove('bg-light');
    elem.classList.add('bg-danger');
}

itemMouseLeave(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    let elem = event.target;

    elem.classList.remove('bg-danger');
    elem.classList.add('bg-light');
}
```

here i attach gif

[image: react strange]

is there any solution to do this in react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by use react `bind` and `state`

```
{(function(rows, i, len) {
    while (++i <= len) {
    rows.push (<div
        key={i.toString()}
        className={"col-sm-3 " + (that.state.itemSelected === i ? 'bg-danger' : 'bg-light') + " mb-1 p-3 parent"}
        style={that.styles.item}
        onMouseEnter={that.itemMouseEnter.bind(that, i)}
        onMouseLeave={that.itemMouseLeave.bind(that, i)}>
        <center>
            <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close" style={that.styles.closeButton}>
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div className="rounded-circle img-responsive mb-3" style={that.styles.image} />
            <h4>VicoErv</h4>
        </center>
    </div>)
    }

    return rows;
})([], 0, 10)}
```

event function

```
itemMouseEnter(id, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let elem = e.target;

    this.setState({itemSelected: id})
}

itemMouseLeave(id, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let elem = e.target;

    this.setState({itemSelected: false});
}
```

Comment: where are you keeping track of `that`?

Comment: inside `render()` scope, declare before `return`